# Static method as part of a contract

Tags: c#, interface, static-methods

I am implementing an infrastructure for access control of models in a web application. The library has a context class that controllers (and maybe views) use for determining if the current user has access to a certain object. For keeping relevant information close to the target object, I've decided to pass on the access check request to the models themselves from the context object.

Implementing this mechanism for model object modification is almost trivial. Declare an interface, say, `ICheckModifyAccess`; and implement it in your model. The same goes for delete check. In both these cases, it is possible to ask an instance of a model whether it is OK to modify or delete them.

Unfortunately, it is not the case for read and create operations. These operations require that I ask the question to the model *class*. So using an interface for this is not an option.

I ended up creating an attribute, `CheckCreateAccessAttribute`, and then ended up using this attribute to mark a static function as the interface function. Then, in my context object, I can use reflection to check if such a marked function exists, if it matches the signature I expect, and eventually call it. In case it makes a difference, the method for create access check is `public bool CanCreate<TObj>();`. A typical model that supports access control would add something like the following to the class:

```
[CheckCreateAccess]
public static bool CanCreate()
{
    return true;
}
```

I am not very fluent in C# yet, and I have a nagging feeling that I'm doing something wrong. Can you suggest a more elegant alternative? Especially, can you get rid of examining `TObj` by reflection?

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you have an instance of the model for create and read operations?

Comment: Elegance, for the main reason. For example, I want to create a list of all users. If I put it in an interface, in order to check for read access I will need to instantiate a dummy user, ask if I can read using this instance, and then go ahead and create the list if I am allowed. With the above approach, I ask if I can read objects of this class, then read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've combined concerns in your object classes instead of [separating them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The temptation to "keep relevant information close to the target object" has perhaps led you to this structure.

Perhaps you could instead handle permissions in a separate class, see for example [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ekstremalna-przerobka-asp-net--czesc6-podzial-obowiazkow.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like good advice. Maybe I can create a generic class that implements the default access control rules, and specialize them for each of my models (am I thinking too much C++?). Or maybe I can simply go with svick's advice and chuck all rules in a single class.

Comment: Good article link. I wish I could +2. It will help organize the usage side of things on the controllers.

Comment: As I suspected, template specialization is a very C++ way to do this. I will need to figure out another way. In any case, separation of concerns was a very good advice. It removes the coupling between my model objects and this particular application and its access control rules - allowing them to be reused in other projects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't ask some specific user whether you can modify him (unless the modify right is per concrete entity). Just create a class that handles the rights (or use appropriate existing class).

This would eliminate your need for static classes and reflection.

If you are going to have lots of types, with custom rules (i.e. code) for every one of them, you could have a generic abstract type (interface or abstract class) that is able to check the rules for one type and some repository to retrieve the specific instance.

Comment: This is also one of the alternative approaches we are considering. The downside for this is that the class implementing access control rules for everyone gets larger as you add more models. The upside is, everything is simple, nice and centralized. There are also common rules such as "a user can modify his own post, but not others'". So ACL for modification involves looking at the insides of models in some cases. So asking the model itself looks more fitting.